# issue running a batch script to kill a process

Tags: batch-file, process, awk, ksh, kill

I am using the following script on a command line to kill a hypothetical notepad process (using a KornShell (ksh) in Windows XP, if that matters):

> kill $(tasklist | grep -i notepad.exe | awk '{print 2}')

Now I take this line, and put it into a batch file c:\temp\testkill.bat, thinking that I should just as well be able to kill the process by running the batch file. However, when I run the batch file, I get the following awk error about unbalanced parentheses:

> C:/Temp> ./testkill.bat
>
> C:\Temp>kill $(tasklist   | grep -i notepad.exe   | awk '{print $2}')
>   awk: unbalanced ()  Context is:
>   >>>     {print $2})     <<<
>   C:/Temp>

So I am baffled as to why I am getting this error about unbalanced parentheses when I run this script via a batch file, but have no issues when I run the command directly from the command line?

(I am not necessarily tied to this way of killing a process - I am additionally wondering why if I write the following on the command line:

> tasklist | grep -i notepad.exe | awk '{print $2}' | kill

The process ID that comes out of the tasklist/grep/awk calls does not seem to properly get piped to kill.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you making a batch file if you have a Korn shell?  Write a shell script - that will probably help you out a lot.

I can answer your final question - `kill` doesn't take the PID to kill from the standard input, it takes it on the command line.  You can use `xargs` to make it work:

```
tasklist | grep -i notepad.exe | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @carl-norum. Your mention of xargs does resolve my second question. However, if I now instead put this line with xargs into the batch file, while I don't get an error, the process does not get killed.

I am a total novice - for something this simple, I am not sure if I understand what is the difference between putting this one line in a batch file versus a shell script? E.g., if I call this file testkill.sh and run 'sh testkill.sh' from the command line, I still have the same issue that there are no errors, but the process doesn't get killed.

Comment: @user657064 - how are you running the Korn shell?  I think cygwin's PIDs don't necessarily line up with Windows' process IDs, for example.

Comment: @carl-norum: I run the Korn shell through MKS Toolkit. In the exact same Korn shell session, I can open up Windows notepad, run the command you wrote and it will kill the notepad process, but if I reopen notepad and then run the batch file or shell script instead, notepad doesn't get killed. I would have thought that the point of parsing tasklist with grep / awk would mean that I'd be able to kill the process regardless of its PID. Moreover, I get the same PID when I run ps instead of tasklist.